# Docker compose does not work for Selenium CSharp as expected

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose

I have Docker for Windows on my machine and I want to start with one HUB 2 nodes at a ubuntu client, one for FireFox and one for Chrome, and both are running in parallel. There for I have C# code, it runs perfectly when I run the : HUB, node-chrome-debug, and node-firefox-debug separately, one by one like this from Windows POWERSHELL: :
docker run -d -p 4446:4444 --name selenium-hub -P selenium/hub
docker run -d -P --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-chrome-debug
docker run -d -P --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-firefox-debug

But if I want do the SAME with Docker compose file, I run into problems....

The question is: what is wrong with this Docker compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
seleniumhub:
  image: selenium/hub
  ports:
    - 4444:4444   
firefoxnode:
  image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
  ports:
    - 4577
  links:
    - seleniumhub:hub          
chromenode:
  image: selenium/node-chrome-debug      
  ports:
    - 4578
  links:
     - seleniumhub:hub
```

I'm Running The following CSharp code:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System;
using Assert = NUnit.Framework.Assert;
namespace SeleniumParalelTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    [Parallelizable]
    public class FirefoxTesting : Hooks
    {
        public FirefoxTesting() : base(BrowserType.Firefox)
        {
        }
        [Test]
        public void FirefoxGoogleTest()
        {

            Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.selenium.dev/");
            Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
            Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='banner-blm']/h2/strong"));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);

           
        }
    }
    [TestFixture]
    [Parallelizable]
    public class ChromeTesting : Hooks
    {
            public ChromeTesting() : base(BrowserType.Chrome)
            { 
            }

        [Test]
        public void ChromeGoogleTest()
        {

            Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.selenium.dev/");
            Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
            Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='banner-blm']/h2/strong"));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I come in problems".. In which problems?

Comment: From the command line if i use:
 
docker run -d -p 4446:4444 --name selenium-hub -P selenium/hub

docker run -d -P --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-chrome-debug

docker run -d -P --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-firefox-debug
 
C code with HOOKS.cs  and driver   Driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4446/wd/hub"), caps);  //Remote

Then it works!!

Comment: If I run docker-compose up from the same directorey as the project file of CSharp project the the HUB exists immediately :

C:\Users\ahmet\source\repos\SeleniumParalelTestDocker> docker-compose up

chromenode_1   | Not linked with a running Hub container
chromenode_1   | 2021-02-18 08:02:34,999 INFO exited: selenium-node (exit status 1; not expected)
firefoxnode_1  | Not linked with a running Hub container
firefoxnode_1  | 2021-02-18 08:02:35,004 INFO exited: selenium-node (exit status 1; not expected)

I see it starts chromeNode,Firefoxnode and then it starts seleniumhub!!
WHY?